# Is log rotation possible for LTTNG?

Tags: logging, lttng

Is it possible to apply a size limit on traces collected by Lttng or overwrite the old traces.

/lttng-relayd.lin64 -C tcp://0.0.0.0:5347 -D tcp://0.0.0.0:5348 -L net://localhost:5349 -o **lttng-traces** -b --working-directory=/tmp

I'm observing disk-full error on my PC if I let the monitor to run continuously, So I want to limit the size of trace collection folder lttng-traces.

Answer (score 0):

The relay daemon is not responsible for managing size -- the sessions are. See [lttng enable-channel](https://lttng.org/man/1/lttng-enable-channel/v2.8/).

For example, limiting a userspace channel to 5MB of traces:

```
lttng create
lttng enable-channel -u --tracefile-size=5242880 my-channel
```

For example, having 10 logs of 5MB each, overwriting old ones (i.e. max 50MB):

```
lttng create
lttng enable-channel -u --tracefile-count=10 --tracefile-size=5242880 my-channel
```